# How much did different kinds of ports cost to add to a 1980's home computer?

Tags: hardware, history, connector

These days it's mostly converged on USB, but in the old days computers tended to have lots of different kinds of ports. In particular, I'm interested in:

- 9-pin serial
- 25-pin serial
- parallel printer
- external disk drive
- Atari joystick
- IBM keyboard
- Ethernet

How much did each of these kind of ports cost to add to a 1980's home computer, in the old days? If exact figures aren't available, I'd be interested in an overall order of magnitude figure plus some idea of the differences, e.g. how much cheaper is 9-pin serial compared to 25-pin?

I'm specifically interested in Z80-based computers (e.g. ZX Spectrum).

Okay, for more specificity: yeah, ZX Spectrum is a representative particular machine, and I'm interested in total extra cost, the connector plus any chips needed to drive the port that weren't already necessary in the machine. I'm only interested in variable cost, not fixed, so the cost of developing any driver software can be ignored (though if it would be large, the cost of ROM space can't).

Comment: The only difference between 9-pin serial and 25-pin serial is in the connector (all signals are the same, many pins remain unconnected), so the difference in cost is neglegible. Note that 25-pin serial was standard for a long time, and the 9-pin serial was introduced at some point in the PC era IIRC, which is why you had often both options (for compatibility) for quite some time. As for prices in general, I can't help you.

Comment: The physical connectors were more expensive back then, but big expense was often with the extra chips needed. An RS-232 serial port would require a UART and a pair of MC1488/1489 driver chips, along with a +/- 12V power supply. That's why the C64 didn't have one, it bit-banged a TTL level serial connection through its user port edge connector. Did the same thing for it's serial connection to the disk drive and printers.

Comment: One way of getting some idea of the total cost of the ports with their associated electronics would be to find the cost of PC expansion boards with the ports, in isolation (serial, parallel, IBM PC joystick and Ethernet).

Comment: In some (especially newer) cases the cost is exacerbated by patent/license fees, often connected with certification fees (to include certain interface in your device you need to get it certified with the standard's owner, and pay a fee per each device on top of hefty certification fee.) This isn't as common with "legacy" interfaces.

Comment: An external disk drive could have a marginal cost for the port of everything from zero (connected to parallell port, say) to hundreds of dollars or more for the simple case (external SCSI, for example). And that's just one example. Also, what do you consider to be "the old days"? Ten years hence? Thirty years? Fifty years?

Comment: As currently written, this is very broad.  As @MichaelKjörling suggests: What computer? Hardware only or cost with driver?  Also, when? To me, "old days" is before 1950.

Comment: You have made this question less broad, but the answer will still vary between computers. I assumed that you meant "home computers", which cuts it down a bit. But there are still a few more broad things (e.g. do you mean just the ports or ports + driver chips required to make things work?). Every time you edit the question it goes back into the queue of questions to potentially reopen, so your edits won't be missed.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Okay, more specifics added.

Comment: @Ross Ridge yep, either a -12V power supply or driver chips like the MAX232 with a built in DC-DC converter (expensive!).

Comment: I don't see how this question could ever be answered because there were hundreds of computer companies in the 80's and each one of them had various deals for sourcing parts and not all of that was made public.  In other words, a DB-9 had a different cost on a Commodore 64 than a Coleco ADAM.

Comment: I've already posted this link on another of your questions, but the advert on page 77 of [this magazine](https://www.scribd.com/doc/130820061/Radio-Electronics-Magazine-08-August-1981) can again help: the easiest way to add a serial port to a Z80 system would be to use the Z80-DART peripheral IC, which according to the advert cost $15 in 1981 for the version compatible with the Z80A.  Connectors and miscellaneous costs should add no more than $2, I would imagine.

Comment: Parallel printer ports are a little simpler than serial ports, and just need address decoding logic (a couple of 74xxx series chips, which generally cost less than 50c each) and a couple of buffer chips (also dirt cheap), but the connector is more expensive (I'd guess still no more than $5, however).

Comment: Joysticks are trivial.  The hardware for the well-known "kempston" interface consists of [2 7400 series ICs and a DB9 connector](http://mdfs.net/Info/Comp/Spectrum/Circuits/Joy2IC.gif).  The box to put it in would be substantially more expensive than the circuitry.

Comment: Disk drives are a little more troublesome.  Data transfer rates for disk drives are quite high in comparison to the capabilities of a machine like the spectrum.  For example, a 5 1/4" 80 track disk would usually run at 300 RPM and have 10 x 512-byte sectors per track.  A sector read would require transfering those 512 bytes to main memory as they're read (otherwise the drive would need its own memory and processor, making it somewhat more expensive), which happens over a period of 1/500th of a second. That's only 13 clock cycles per byte on a spectrum, and with even the simplest instruction...

Comment: ... on a Z80 taking at least 4 clock cycles, you just don't have time to handle it using programmed IO, so you need DMA.  The computer processor could probably handle sending the right signals to the stepper motors etc to control the mechanics of a drive, but a DMA controller to manage the transfer isn't going to be cheap.  Look at a minimum cost of $50 for the hardware there, I guess.  And then the physical drive read/write mechanism is non-trivial too, so probably at least $100 for the whole thing.

Comment: Ethernet also would be tricky.  Even in its original version, the data transfer rates were higher still than the floppy drive: approximately 3Mb/s, so it too would require a DMA system. The physical interface wouldn't be too tricky though, so I guess it could have been done for around $60.  The PC keyboard uses a standard serial protocol, so the cost for this is essentially the same as a serial port.

Comment: @RossRidge the price of the connectors was negligible compared to the custom electronics design and chips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1985 I paid $50 for a parallel printer adapter for my Atari 800xl to connect it to a standard Canon printer. The most popular one at the time called an ape face was around $60. The Atari 850 interface which was both serial and parallel was coming down in price but was still over $100. The 1050 disk drive was around $180 while the non Atari drives that were true double density or quad density started at $350 up to $700. The hard drives at the time all came with their own interface boards that only worked with the specific drive that came with it. I remember 5 mb drives being around $1000 and Corvus which had an interface board that also networked Atari's together and some other functions I don't recall sold a 20 mb drive which was close to $3000. I remember many home brew type joystick interfaces that could use the basic Atari stick with many systems but I don't remember prices.